# Как реализовать фичу у себя на сайте?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Доброе утро всем. Увидел на одном [сайте](http://narko-stop.com) интересную фичу. Хочу повторить на одном своем [проекте](http://www.alkonarkostop.com.ua). С чего лучше начать? Можно ли реализовать такое на jQuery? Подскажите, пожалуйста, в какую сторону копать?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На сайте с фичей* стоит "RokSlideshow"-слайдер. Это плагин для Joomla. Если у тебя Joomla, качай плагин, загружай и радуйся, что всё работает. )

2-й вариант - погуглить jQuery Slider - будет много слайдеров с демо.

3-й - написать свой слайдер изображений, меняя размер картинки с помощью jQuery .animate()

Answer (score 1):

Копать в сторону метода animate().

Если посмотреть веб-инспектором на эту фичу, то видно, что у картинки просто-напросто меняется размер и положение.

Answer (score 1):

Да, это и делается обычно на jQuery. И если не жалко времени, то делается не очень сложно, но есть все-таки уже готовые вещи:
Конкретно там, если я правильно разобрался, то это модуль для джумлы RokSlideshow Module.
А по большому счету обычный слайдер, коих немерено. Один из популярных это "Nivo":
https://github.com/gilbitron/Nivo-Slider